# Quick, Petty Java Question: Parenthesis around SQLException

Tags: java, parentheses

```
  try {
      ...
  }  catch (SQLException sqle) {
      String theError = (sqle).getSQLState();
      ...
  }
```

What does surrounding `sqle` with parenthesis do?  Anything?

Just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick reply - Nothing.

Longer reply - It might be a vestigial remnant of an inline cast:

```
((SomeMoreSpecificException)sqle).get...
```